# multiple locks on different elements of an array

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

If I have 8 threads, and an array of 1,000,000,000 elements in an array, I can have 1,000,000,000 mutices where the index represents the element within the array that is being locked and written to. However this is fairly wasteful to me and requires a lot of memory.

Is there a way that I can only use 8 mutices and have the same functionality?

Comment: How are you accessing the elements? Are any elements shared between threads? If so how many? There are a lot of unknowns here. Can you give more details about your code?

Comment: Divide the array in 8 parts.

Comment: Split the array into 8 parts of `125,000,000` each.

Comment: What are the elements? - if they are basic types (like integers) and depending what you are trying to do (like just increment them or such) it might be possible to use `std::atomic<type>` - but there is not really enough info to know - maybe some example code?

Comment: I don't want to split the array into 8 parts because that will cause a high likelihood of waiting (access is random). The elements of the array are a class that I will write that will be multiple Golomb coded values.

Comment: Can you post the new information in the question itself? You want to guard a billion elements using 8 mutexes. I just don't think there is a loaves and fishes solution here to be honest. I suspect that some additional contention is inevitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking out aloud here... and not really sure how efficient this would be, but:

You could create method of locking certain indexes:

```
vector<int> mutexed_slots;
std::mutex mtx;

bool lock_element(int index) 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // Check if item is in the mutexed list
    if ( !std::find(mutexed_slots.begin(), mutexed_slots.end(), index) != vector.end() ) 
    {
       // If its not then add it - now that array value is safe from other threads
       mutexed_slots.emplace_back(index);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void unlock_element(int index) 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // No need to check because you will only unlock the element that you accessed (unless you are a very naughty boy indeed)
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);
}
```

**Note:** This is the start of a idea, so don't knock it too hard just yet! Its also un-tested pseudo code. Its not really intended as a final answer - but as a start point. Please add comments to improve or to suggest that is is/isn't plausible.

Further points:

- There may be a more efficient STL to use
- You could probably wrap all of this up in a class along with your data
- You would need to loop through `lock_element()` until it returns true - again not pretty at the moment. This mechanism could be improved.
- Each thread needs to remember which index they currently are working on so that they only unlock that particular one - again this could be more integrated within a class to ensure that behaviour.

But as a concept - workable? I would think if you need really fast access (which maybe you do) this might not be that efficient, thoughts?

**Update**

This could be made much more efficient if each thread/worker "registers" its own entry in `mutexed_slots`. Then there would no push_back/remove's from the vector (except at the start/end). So each thread just sets the index that it has locked - if it has nothing locked then it just gets set to -1 (or such). I am thinking there are many more such efficiency improvements to be made. Again a complete class to do all this for you would be the way to implement it.

---

## Testing / Results

I implemented a tester for this, just because I quite enjoy that sort of thing. My implementation is [here](https://github.com/code-fodder/big_protected_array)

I think its a public github repo - so you are welcome to take a look. But I posted the results on the top-level readme (so scroll a little to see them). I implemented some improvements such that:

- There are no insert/removal to the protection array at run-time
- There is no need for a lock_guard to do the "unlock" because I am relying no a std::atomic index.

  Below is my a printout of my summary:

### Summary:

When the workload is 1ms (the time taken to perform each action) then the amount of work done was:

- 9808 for protected
- 8117 for normal

  **Note** these values varied, sometimes the normal was higher, there appeared no clear winner.

When the workload is 0ms (basically increment a few counters) then the amount of work done was:

- 9791264 for protected
- 29307829 for normal

So here you can see that using the mutexed protection slows down the work by a factor of about a third (1/3). This ratio is consistant between tests.

I also ran the same tests for 1 worker, and the same ratios roughly held true. However when I make the array smaller (~1000 elements) the amount of work done is still roughly the same for when the work load is 1ms. But when the workload is very light I got results like:

- 5621311
- 39157931

  Which is about 7 times slower.

#### Conclusion

- The larger the array then less collisions occur - the performance is better.
- The longer the work load is (per item) then the less noticeable the difference is with using the protecting mechanism.

It appears that the locking is generally only adding an overhead that is 2-3 times slower then incrementing a few counters. This is probably skewed by actual collisions because (from the results) the longest lock time recorded was a huge 40ms - but this was when there was the work time was very fast so, many collisions occurred (~8 successful locks per collision).

Comment: This is definitely interesting. However I suspect you may have some false economies here. If I understand your intention, you want to substitute a lock held for a very small time (to flip a flag) in place of a lock held for a long time (while the work gets done). You will have all your threads queueing on a single mutex. On the surface that might be fine if the work done takes relatively longer than the time required to obtain a mutex. However, even if obtaining the mutex is relatively fast, those threads that check the flag and discover they have to wait for the flag to clear then have to ...

Comment: ... wait for the other thread to finish doing the work on that index, which we are assuming here will be relatively long. So how long do you make your waiting thread sleep for before re-acquiring the mutex to test the flag again? Or do you just let it keep trying like a *spinlock*? I suspect the former would never be as efficient as waiting on an actual mutex while the latter will likely burn a lot of CPU....

Comment: @Galik yes you have it exactly I think - its really the start of an idea, not a fleshed out one. There are definite issues here. If, as you say, "do work" takes a while, then this would probably work fairly well - the chance of a collision is 0.00000008% (did not count the zero's) so waiting for another task to finish won't happen that much of the % of the time. But the bottle next is the single mutex. I would say its worth trying somthing simple like this - measure the performance and then improve from there....

Comment: Yes you could be right here. Your pseudo-mutexes are less efficient to lock than a genuine mutex if the index is already held but (should be) more efficient to lock if the index is free (assuming work is big compared to locking). And the ratio of free to held is large and therefore should (hopefully) far outweigh the cost.

Comment: @Galik Yeah, I am assuming the `lock_element()` will return true very very often. But probably more info on the nature of the "work" and some profiling is needed here to find the right balance...  the question is a bit light on details : )

Comment: @Galik just for fun/interest, I did an implementation to get some results (see the update) - would be interested what you think... it does not look to bad, although there is definitely  some overhead...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the access pattern, do you have a way to partition the work effectively? Basically, you can partition the array into 8 chunks (or as many as you can afford) and cover each part with a mutex, but if  the access pattern is random you're still going to have a lot of collisions.

Do you have TSX support on your system? it would be a classic example, just have one global lock, and have the threads ignore it unless there's an actual collision.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class that will create locks on the fly when a particular index requires it, `std::optional` would be helpful for this (C++17 code ahead):

```
class IndexLocker {
  public:
    explicit IndexLocker(size_t size) : index_locks_(size) {}

    std::mutex& get_lock(size_t i) {
        if (std::lock_guard guard(instance_lock_); index_locks_[i] == std::nullopt) {
            index_locks_[i].emplace();
        }
        return *index_locks_[i];
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::optional<std::mutex>> index_locks_;
    std::mutex instance_lock_;
};
```

You could also use `std::unique_ptr` to minimize stack-space but maintain identical semantics:

```
class IndexLocker {
  public:
    explicit IndexLocker(size_t size) : index_locks_(size) {}

    std::mutex& get_lock(size_t i) {
        if (std::lock_guard guard(instance_lock_); index_locks_[i] == nullptr) {
            index_locks_[i] = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
        }
        return *index_locks_[i];
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>> index_locks_;
    std::mutex instance_lock_;
};
```

---

Using this class doesn't necessarily mean you need to create all 1,000,000 elements. You can use modulo operations to treat the locker as a "hash table" of mutexes:

```
constexpr size_t kLockLimit = 8;
IndexLocker index_locker(kLockLimit);

auto thread_code = [&](size_t i) {
    std::lock_guard guard(index_locker.get_lock(i % kLockLimit));
    // Do work with lock.
};
```

Worth mentioning that the "hash table" approach makes it very easy to deadlock (`get_lock(0)` followed by `get_lock(16)`, for example). If each thread does work on exactly one element at a time, however, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That's an interesting improvement on my idea - should have less bottlenecks (mine has only one mutex which will probably hinder performance)...

Answer (score 0):

There are other trade-offs with fine-grain locking. Atomic operations are expensive, so a parallel algorithm that locks every element can take longer than the sequential version.

How to lock efficiently depends. Are the array elements dependent on other elements in the array? Are you mostly reading? mostly writing?

> I don't want to split the array into 8 parts because that will cause a
>   high likelihood of waiting (access is random). The elements of the
>   array are a class that I will write that will be multiple Golomb coded
>   values.

I don't think having 8 mutexes is the way to go here. If a given lock protects an array section, you can't switch it to protect a different section in the midst of parallel execution without introducing a race condition (rendering the mutex pointless).

Are the array items small? If you can get them down to 8 bytes, you can declare your class with `alignas(8)` and instantiate `std::atomic<YourClass>` objects. (Size depends on architecture. Verify `is_lock_free()` returns true.) That could open up the possibility of lock-free algorithms. It almost seems like a variant of hazard pointers would be useful here. That's complex, so it's probably better to look into other approaches to parallelism if time is limited.